# Compute matrix inversion / multiplication using a black box

Tags: algorithms, matrices, matrix-multiplication

Suppose you're given a black box $A$, and you're told $A$ can invert a matrix (assuming the matrix is invertible) $M$ in $O(T_A)$. You're also given a black box $B$, and you're told $B$ can multiply two matrices $X$ and $Y$ in $O(T_B)$.

**There are two problems as follow:**

- How is it possible to compute $X \times Y$ by just using $A$ in $O(T_A)$?
- How is it possible to compute $X^{-1}$ by just using $B$ in $O(T_B)$?

**Some ideas that come to mind:**

We already know that if $X$ is invertible, then:

$$X\times X^{-1}=I$$

where $I$ is an identity matrix. But how can I compute $X^{-1}$? Any hint will be constructive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was shown in 1969, by Strassen, that matrix multiplication and matrix inversion have the same computational complexity.

Details can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_matrix_multiplication#Matrix_inversion,_determinant_and_Gaussian_elimination).